# Water entering into fireplace during rain

Tags: water, fireplace, chimney

I recently observed water is coming in the fireplace during the rain. Although it is about  a drop per second or so, it is can easily fill up a small pan during a stormy and rainy day.

I don't think this is normal. I have a flue cap at the top of my chimney. Is this normal behavior?

Also what can the possible causes of it be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like your [chimney cap](http://www.woodlanddirect.com/Chimney-Cap-For-Lyemance-Damper?gclid=CLC7hY_av8ICFfIF7AodKmAALQ?gdftrk=gdfV23673_a_7c1677_a_7c8224_a_7c2522410_a2s__a3a__a2s_2522412#Lyemance%20Damper%20Dimensions:13%22_x_13%22) top might have flew off for that much water to come in.  Mine just a few months ago and I had to secure it with extra screws.  I would check that first.

If it is only coming inside the chimney it really has to be top of the cap or that you need caulking around the base of your cap.

Comment: thanks, Just checked the chimney cap it is still there. I need to check the caulking around the base of cap, will check once the rains stops. Can it be seeping to the chimney camber from the flashing area? Mainly the portion where the cap flashing is attached to the chimney (near the roof intersection)

Comment: I can't see how you would be getting a lot of water inside the chimney and non in your house/outside the chimney area if you had a flashing issue.

Comment: Thats surprise me also. Most probably it might be a caulking issue. I will check this out once the rain stops. Thanks for you help!

Comment: In your opinion Can chimney cap caulking cause this issue?

Comment: If you have a point on the top of your chimney that dips and holds a little water, everything will funnel there and then go out the easiest way.  You could also have a crack on your chimney crown (that cap sits on) and that may need caulk.  Almost all issues with water coming in the chimney are pretty easy to fix.  Can figure out the exact cause with a bucket of water and testing on your roof (if that is possible).

Answer (score 2):

Flue cap is not waterproof, especially in wind. I am talking from experience. We have two chimneys, one with regular flue cap:

[image: regular flue cap]

and the other with a directionalflue cap similar to this:

[image]

From my experience, the directional version works much better, but requires some maintenance, like occasional lubricating (like once a year is more than enough).

Answer (score 0):

During heavy rain with wind, that sounds normal because water is getting in the side of the cap. If a smoke can come out then water can get in as well